# Creating a model for a json

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to build a Azure cognitive text translator app in angular. Initially I need to load the supported languages. But when I use this link `https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/languages?api-version=3.0`. I'm getting response like this

```
"translation": {
    "af": {
        "name": "Afrikaans",
        "nativeName": "Afrikaans",
        "dir": "ltr"
    },
    "ar": {
        "name": "Arabic",
        "nativeName": "العربية",
        "dir": "rtl"
    },
    "bg": {
        "name": "Bulgarian",
        "nativeName": "Български",
        "dir": "ltr"
    },
    ...
}
```

How to create a model that holds this type of json?

When I tried json2ts.com for building the model, it creates object for each language like

```
export interface Af {
    name: string;
    nativeName: string;
    dir: string;
}

export interface Ar {
    name: string;
    nativeName: string;
    dir: string;
}

export interface Bg {
    name: string;
    nativeName: string;
    dir: string;
}

export interface Translation {
    af: Af;
    ar: Ar;
    bg: Bg;
}
```

Do I need to create interface for all the available languages?
are there any other simple way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `translation` property of that object is a key-value map.
You could model the whole thing as follows:

```
type Dir = "ltr" | "rtl";

interface Translation {
  name:string;
  nativeName:string;
  dir: Dir;
}

interface LangResponse {
  translation: {[langCode:string]: Translation};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a Typescript interface modeling the JSON data.

```
export interface LanguageInfo {
  name: string
  nativeName: string
  dir: string
  code?: string
  toScripts?: Array<LanguageInfo>
}

export interface TranslationLanguages {
  langCode: string
  info: LanguageInfo
}

function fromJSON(json_data: string | Object): TranslationLanguages {
  let obj: TranslationLanguages;

  if (typeof json_data === "object") {
    obj = json_data as TranslationLanguages;
  } else {
    obj = JSON.parse(json_data);
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan See updated answer with example `fromJSON` function.